# Coordinates or origin of screen below navigation bar for iphone

Tags: ios, navigationbar, bounds

I would like to get the coordinates of the origin of screen below the navigation bar or toplayout guide in Storyboard.  Normally I believe this is 64 but on my iphone XR it seems to be more than that so I'd like to get it exactly programmatically.

[This post](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/ipad-navigation-bar-and-toolbar-height-changes-in-ios-12-91c5766809f4) goes into changes in the height of the navigation bar in ios 12

I tried the following but this gives the origin of the whole view without compensating for the navigation bar:

```
CGFloat mainViewOriginY = self.view.bounds.origin.y;
```

How can I progrmatticaly get the y coordinate of the origin at the bottom of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by starting with bounds and adding the navigation bar height which you can get and the the status bar height which you can also get as follows:

```
CGFloat statHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarFrame.size.height;
CGFloat nbHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat startY = self.view.bounds.origin.y+ statHeight + nbHeight;
```